# How do I input multiple indexes into a bootstrap select val method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to pass in multiple values into a bootstrap select like this

```
$('#teacherStyles').selectpicker('val', [0,1,2]);
```

I have an array that has all the values (1,2,3,etc,etc)

but I can't just do a

```
$('#teacherStyles').selectpicker('val', [allSelectedIndexes.join(',')]);
```

because this creates a string and passes a string inside the brackets.

How can I pass just the values separated by a comma into the brackets from an array?

Comment: What about `$('#teacherStyles').selectpicker('val', allSelectedIndexes);`

Comment: seems to work! thanks!